# Struct for JSON Response

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm trying to workout how the type-struct should be for this JSON response.
from CryptoWatch https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/kraken/btcusd/ohlc?periods=60

```
{
  "result": {
    "60": [
      [
        1490733900,
        1027.001,
        1027.001,
        1027,
        1027,
        0.024999999
      ],
      [
        1490733960,
        1027,
        1027,
        1027,
        1027,
        12.61904
      ],
      [
        1490778360,
        1037.749,
        1037.749,
        1037.749,
        1037.749,
        0.0052474597
      ]
    ]
  },
  "allowance": {
    "cost": 1234,
    "remaining": 456677
  }
}
```

1. I've tried the JSON-TO-GoLang-Struct service.

   type AutoGenerated struct {
       Result struct {
           Num60 []struct {
           Num0 int `json:"0"`
           Num1 float64 `json:"1"`
           Num2 float64 `json:"2"`
           Num3 int `json:"3"`
           Num4 int `json:"4"`
           Num5 float64 `json:"5"`
           } `json:"60"`
   } `json:"result"`
           Allowance struct {
               Cost int `json:"cost"`
               Remaining int `json:"remaining"`
           } `json:"allowance"`
   }

   code-formatting seems broken :/

It seems to get stuck on array-to-struct error when i tried to decode it.

2. I don't want to use the map+interface method for this struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. You can put the result as `map[string][][]float64` also. But this is more readable I think.

```
type Result [][]float64

type Response struct {
    Result    map[string]Result `json:"result"`
    Allowance struct {
        Cost      int `json:"cost"`
        Remaining int `json:"remaining"`
    } `json:"allowance"`
}
```